# How to call Twitter's POST /statuses/filter with 5000 user ids?

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

Both GET and POST methods supported by [the endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter). The POST method is recommended to call endpoint with a huge number of user ids to follow, because the GET method will lead to an oversized URL that the server can't handle. How the "follow" parameter can be passed in the body of the request?

UPD: here is what I've already tried using Insomnia (the URL is always 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json' and the method is always 'POST' and the server response is always "No filter parameters found. Expect at least one parameter: follow track locations"):

**A plain text body with Content-Type: text/html**

```
follow=2731236345
```

**A json body with Content-Type: application/json**

```
{
    "follow": "2731236345"
}
```

**Another json body**

```
{
    "follow": [
        2731236345
    ]
}
```

However, when I use form-url-encoded with field "follow" and the value "2731236345" I receive the response "Unauthorized".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider looking at the [Twitter Developer Labs new endpoint](https://twittercommunity.com/t/new-filtered-stream-endpoints-available-in-labs-and-the-future-of-statuses-filter/129888), because this existing API will be retired, likely (but not yet confirmed) in 2020.

When you say "without any success", what libraries are you using, and at what levels of query parameters - you're not being very clear about what is not working here. 5000 user IDs is very large. Can you please be more specific about the errors you're seeing, and the code you're trying to run?

Comment: Thank you, Andy! I've added some details to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to connect using curl:

```sh
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json' \
  --header 'authorization: <censored>' \
  --data 'follow=2731236345'
```

The same request doesn't work in Insomnia for some reason, but it doesn't matter for the goal of this post.